# Translate Matlab matrix concatenation to Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, concatenation, translate

How to translate the following matlab code for matrix concatenation to python?

```
nr_a = 10;
nc_a = 23;
nr_b = 500;
a = zeros(nr_a, nc_a);
b = zeros(nr_b, nc_a - 1);
c = zeros(nr_b, 1);
d = [ a; b c];
```

In python, d.shape should equal (nr_a+nr_b, nc_a).
My incorrect python solution is

```
d = np.block([a, [b, c]])
```

Comment: Have you tried `np.concatenate()` ?

Comment: I did use np concatenate in another location for appending column concatenation. It may apply here too.   Let me look at it for a few minutes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```py
import numpy as np

nr_a = 10
nc_a = 23
nr_b = 500
a = np.zeros((nr_a, nc_a))
b = np.zeros((nr_b, nc_a - 1))
c = np.zeros((nr_b, 1))
d = np.concatenate((a, np.concatenate((b, c), axis=1)))
```

Comment: [Good documentation](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/04/how-to-concatenate-arrays-in-numpy/) for whoever needs it.

Answer (score 2):

`np.block` requires you to wrapp `a` in a list as well, like this:

```py
import numpy as np

nr_a = 10
nc_a = 23
nr_b = 500
a = np.zeros((nr_a, nc_a))
b = np.zeros((nr_b, nc_a - 1))
c = np.zeros((nr_b, 1))
d = np.block([[a], [b, c]])

print(d.shape)
```

Output:

```
(510, 23)
```

Internally it just uses `concatenate` recursively, but saves you the trouble of repeating it yourself (and looks much cleaner for bigger usages).